# Data conversion of a list of strings that are numbers separated by commas giving me multiple errors and I'm not able to get the correct output

Tags: python, eof

```
Section 1 Example A: Input of "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" should output 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Section 1 Example B: Input of "1,2,6,4,8" should output 1 2 6 4 8

Section 2 Example C: Input of "1-3,5-9,12,14-15" should output 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 12 14 15
Section 2 Example D: Input of "2-4,3-7,10" should output 2 3 4 3 4 5 6 7 10

Section 3 Example E: Input of "3-1,5-9,12,14-15" should output 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 12 14 15
Section 3 Example F: Input of "2-4,7-3,10" should output 2 3 4 3 4 5 6 7 10
```

I have tried solving this problem and find myself getting either errors such as EOF or I will solve section 1 A but cannot do section 1 b at the same time in a loop. They are supposed to be building off of each other. I am not allowed to do user input so I am very confused on how to solve these problems.

This is my code as of now, which does not get the right outputs and gives me an EOF error. What are some steps i should take to fix these errors.

```py
def PrintNumbers(s):
    a=s.split(',') #split() function returns a list where text between the character ',' becomes a list element
    i=0
    #It is said that negative numbers need not to be accounted so let's replace the negative numbers with 0.
    while i<len(a):
        c=a[i].count('-')
        if c==3: #it means that both the elements in the range are negative possible string representation will be of "-a--b" so we can remove the element from list
            a.remove(a[i])
            i=i-1
        elif c==2: #it means that one of the element is negative possible string will be either "-a-b" or "a--b" so we remo
            if a[i][0]=='-':#if the first element is'-' it means that the first number is negative(possible string is '-a-b') and second one is positive so lets change to first number to '0'
                a[i]=a[i][1:] #taking the whole remaining string and finding the position of next '-' and adding 0 before it
                pos=a[i].find('-')
                a[i]='0'+a[i][pos:]
            else:
                pos=a[i].find('-') #possible string will be of form "a--b" replace the whole value after first '-' with 0
                a[i]=a[i][0:pos+1]+'0'
        else: #it means that the list may be a range like "1-3" or a negative number "-1"
            if a[i][0]=='-': #if first character is negative number then we can change the whole string to '0'
                a.remove(a[i])
                i=i-1
        i+=1
                
    #It is said that ranges are also given so we need to split the list based on the seperator '-'
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i]=a[i].split('-') #We perform split operation to each array index and add the returned list to the same index.
    #If seperator character is not present in the string the whole string returns as a list element
    
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            a[i][j]=a[i][j].strip() #strip() is used to remove white spaces at the starting and ending of the string if they are present
    
    m=-1 #m is used to find the maximum value given in the ranges it is initialized to -1
    
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            if a[i][j].isdigit(): #check if the element is digit or not if digit convert it into integer
                a[i][j]=int(a[i][j])
            else:
                print('Error : Given string contains alphanumeric values ')
                return
            m=max(m,a[i][j]) #updating the value of m to maximum value 
            
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if len(a[i])==2: #if at an index the number of elements are 2 that means it represents range
            if a[i][0]>a[i][1]: #It is said that while representing range the ranges are represented backward so if the second element in range is less than the first element then we swap them 
                a[i][0],a[i][1]=a[i][1],a[i][0]
    #We are told to print the numbers 
    
    #Printing the numbers:
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if len(a[i])==1:
            print(a[i][0],end=' ')
        else:
            for j in range(a[i][0],a[i][1]+1): #printing all numbers in range
                print(j,end=' ')
    
s=input('Enter input : ')
PrintNumbers(s)
```

Comment: You've marked this a Java question, but where is your Java code? How is Java relevant? Why did you use the Java tag?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please share a full error traceback or your results, what have you tried to fix it? etc

Comment: Structure the post as follow: issue description (with clear code), already tried solutions, your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the a-b cases with regex much better

```py
import re
def process_input(input: str)->None:
    to_print = []
    elements = input.split(',')
    for element in elements:
        try:
            num = int(element)
            to_print.append(element)
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass
        numbers = [int(i) for i in re.match(r'(-?\d*)-(-?\d*)',element).group(1,2)]
        for x in range(min(numbers),max(numbers)):
            to_print.append(str(x))
    print(' '.join(to_print))
        
if __name__ == __main__:
    str_input = input('Enter input: ')
    process_input(str_input)
```